# how to search an arraylist of objects for a string

Tags: java, arraylist

I am working on a task where I have to count words in a text. I have created an `ArrayList<Word>` that contains the `Word` isntances. When I scan the text, I am only supposed to add a word to the ArrayList if it does not exists in the list already. If it exists, I am going to increase the value with the method `.increasNumber()`. How do I do this?

```
public ArrayList<Word> list = new ArrayList<Word>();

public void readBook(String fileName) throws Exception {
    String fileRead = fileName;
    Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(fileRead));
    while(file.hasNextLine()) {
        addWord(file.nextLine());
    }
}

private void addWord(String word) {
    if (list.contains(word)) {
        word.increasNumber);
    } else {
        list.add(new Word(word));
    }
}
```

Here are my `Word` class:

```
public class Word {
    String text;
    int count = 0;

    public Word(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return text;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return count;
    }

    public void increasNumber() {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `list` is full of `Word` objects and you are checking if the `list` contains a `String` object.

Comment: Can we see your `Word` class?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a `List`, use a `Map<String,Integer>` where the key is your word and the value the number of occurences.

```
Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
Integer count = map.get(word);
if (count == null) {
  map.put(word, 1);
} else {
  map.put(word, count+1);
}
```

**EDIT** : I misread your OP, @gonzo's comment is right ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should re-write `addWord()` method:

```
List<Word> words = new ArrayList<>();

private void addWord(String word) {
    Word w = new Word(word);
    int i = words.indexOf(w);
    if (i >= 0) {
        words.get(i).increaseNumber();
    } else {
        words.add(w);
    }
}
```

To make this work you also need to override `Word#equals` and `hashCode` to be based on inner content only (i. e. `word1.equals(word2)` should return true if `word1` and `word2` are both based on the same string).